# Magento 2 Database Errors

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, database, error

Getting these errors when I try to delete a product on Magento 2 admin. Can anyone help? Seems like a database issue but this was not happening before and I have not done anything to the database.

```
2 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'webadmin_exc.autosuggest_batch' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `autosuggest_batch` AS `main_table` WHERE (`product_id` = '309') AND (`store_id` = '1')
Exception #1 (PDOException): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'webadmin_exc.autosuggest_batch' doesn't exist

Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'webadmin_exc.autosuggest_batch' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `autosuggest_batch` AS `main_table` WHERE (`product_id` = '309') AND (`store_id` = '1')
#0 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(95): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php(303): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(*)...', Array)
#4 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(465): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(*)...', Array)
#5 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(520): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('SELECT COUNT(*)...', Array)
#6 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(828): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select), Array)
#7 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php(218): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchOne(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select), Array)
#8 /home/webadmin/public_html/app/code/Autocompleteplus/Autosuggest/Helper/Data.php(426): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->getSize()
#9 /home/webadmin/public_html/app/code/Autocompleteplus/Autosuggest/Observer/ProductDelete.php(98): Autocompleteplus\Autosuggest\Helper\Data->writeProductDeletion('test', '309', '1', Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#10 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(73): Autocompleteplus\Autosuggest\Observer\ProductDelete->execute(Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#11 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(61): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(Object(Autocompleteplus\Autosuggest\Observer\ProductDelete), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#12 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(66): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#13 /home/webadmin/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('catalog_product...', Array)
#14 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(835): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch('catalog_product...', Array)
#15 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product.php(1025): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->beforeDelete()
#16 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Observer/BeforeEntityDelete.php(30): Magento\Catalog\Model\Product->beforeDelete()
#17 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(73): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Observer\BeforeEntityDelete->execute(Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#18 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(61): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(Object(Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Observer\BeforeEntityDelete), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#19 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(66): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#20 /home/webadmin/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('magento_catalog...', Array)
#21 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/EventManager.php(51): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch('magento_catalog...', Array)
#22 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Operation/Delete.php(115): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EventManager->dispatchEntityEvent('Magento\\Catalog...', 'delete_before', Array)
#23 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/EntityManager.php(126): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\Delete->execute(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), Array)
#24 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product.php(302): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EntityManager->delete(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#25 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product->delete(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#26 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->___callParent('delete', Array)
#27 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'delete', Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor), Array, 'catalogsearchFu...')
#28 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext/Plugin/Product.php(51): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#29 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext/Plugin/Product.php(37): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Plugin\Product->addCommitCallback(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#30 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Plugin\Product->aroundDelete(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#31 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'delete', Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor), Array, 'clean_quote_ite...')
#32 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Product/Plugin/RemoveQuoteItems.php(35): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#33 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Quote\Model\Product\Plugin\RemoveQuoteItems->aroundDelete(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#34 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'delete', Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor), Array, 'clean_cache')
#35 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/FlushCacheByTags.php(93): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#36 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\FlushCacheByTags->aroundDelete(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#37 /home/webadmin/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->___callPlugins('delete', Array, Array)
#38 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(816): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->delete(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#39 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/MassDelete.php(54): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->delete()
#40 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassDelete->execute()
#41 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(226): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#42 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#43 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassDelete\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#44 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassDelete\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
#45 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#46 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassDelete\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#47 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassDelete\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#48 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassDelete\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#49 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassDelete\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#50 /home/webadmin/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/MassDelete/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassDelete\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#51 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassDelete\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#52 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#53 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#54 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#55 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#56 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#57 /home/webadmin/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#58 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#59 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#60 /home/webadmin/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#61 {main}

Exception #1 (PDOException): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'webadmin_exc.autosuggest_batch' doesn't exist
#0 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(95): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php(303): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(*)...', Array)
#5 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(465): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(*)...', Array)
#6 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(520): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('SELECT COUNT(*)...', Array)
#7 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(828): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select), Array)
#8 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php(218): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchOne(Object(Magento\Framework\DB\Select), Array)
#9 /home/webadmin/public_html/app/code/Autocompleteplus/Autosuggest/Helper/Data.php(426): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->getSize()
#10 /home/webadmin/public_html/app/code/Autocompleteplus/Autosuggest/Observer/ProductDelete.php(98): Autocompleteplus\Autosuggest\Helper\Data->writeProductDeletion('test', '309', '1', Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#11 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(73): Autocompleteplus\Autosuggest\Observer\ProductDelete->execute(Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#12 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(61): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(Object(Autocompleteplus\Autosuggest\Observer\ProductDelete), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#13 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(66): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#14 /home/webadmin/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('catalog_product...', Array)
#15 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(835): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch('catalog_product...', Array)
#16 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product.php(1025): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->beforeDelete()
#17 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Observer/BeforeEntityDelete.php(30): Magento\Catalog\Model\Product->beforeDelete()
#18 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(73): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Observer\BeforeEntityDelete->execute(Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#19 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(61): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(Object(Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Observer\BeforeEntityDelete), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#20 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(66): Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch(Array, Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
#21 /home/webadmin/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('magento_catalog...', Array)
#22 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/EventManager.php(51): Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy->dispatch('magento_catalog...', Array)
#23 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Operation/Delete.php(115): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EventManager->dispatchEntityEvent('Magento\\Catalog...', 'delete_before', Array)
#24 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/EntityManager.php(126): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\Delete->execute(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor), Array)
#25 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product.php(302): Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EntityManager->delete(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#26 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product->delete(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#27 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->___callParent('delete', Array)
#28 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'delete', Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor), Array, 'catalogsearchFu...')
#29 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext/Plugin/Product.php(51): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#30 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/Indexer/Fulltext/Plugin/Product.php(37): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Plugin\Product->addCommitCallback(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#31 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Indexer\Fulltext\Plugin\Product->aroundDelete(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#32 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'delete', Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor), Array, 'clean_quote_ite...')
#33 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Product/Plugin/RemoveQuoteItems.php(35): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#34 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Quote\Model\Product\Plugin\RemoveQuoteItems->aroundDelete(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#35 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'delete', Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor), Array, 'clean_cache')
#36 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/FlushCacheByTags.php(93): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#37 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Framework\App\Cache\FlushCacheByTags->aroundDelete(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#38 /home/webadmin/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->___callPlugins('delete', Array, Array)
#39 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(816): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor->delete(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#40 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/MassDelete.php(54): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->delete()
#41 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassDelete->execute()
#42 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(226): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#43 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#44 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassDelete\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#45 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassDelete\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
#46 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#47 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassDelete\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#48 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Catalog...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassDelete\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#49 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassDelete\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#50 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassDelete\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#51 /home/webadmin/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/MassDelete/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassDelete\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#52 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassDelete\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#53 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#54 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#55 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#56 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#57 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#58 /home/webadmin/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#59 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#60 /home/webadmin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#61 /home/webadmin/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#62 {main}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have issue in a custom module name is `Autocompleteplus_Autosuggest`

The error indicated that this module have a database table `autosuggest_batch` which ***does not exits in your database***.

May be this extension setup upgrade did not not properly

**Solution:**

- First, take database backup
- Then uninstall this extension
- Remove this extension related db,Check setup files
  `app/code/Autocompleteplus/Autosuggest`
- reinstalled it in the proper way

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using the **Mirasvit** extension **Search AutoComplete & Suggest Pro for Magento 2** or a similar.

So check if you have the last version installed and the respective version like Magento 2.0 or 2.1.